# Error when executing Python inference.py script

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on designing a chatbot using tensorflow in python, I have windows 10 (64 bit) installed with python version 3.6.0.
when trying to execute `Python inference.py` I got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "inference.py", line 9, in 
>       from nmt import nmt
>     File "C:\Users\Ali\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SequenceToSequenceModel\nmt-chatbot/nmt\nmt\nmt.py", line 26, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>     File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 59, in 
>       from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
>     File "C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in 
>       from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
>     File "c:\users\ali\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in 
>       from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

I appreciate any help you provide.